# ITK build error when trying to register ImageIOFactory

Tags: image-processing, visual-studio-2012, itk

I'm trying to link to ITK to read/write images with VS2012 (ITK version 4.11). I've built the ITK libraries using cmake; then installed into the install prefix folder. I've used the /include folder in the Additional include folders in my project and also used the following libraries as additional dependencies:

```
itksys-4.11.lib
itkv3p_netlib-4.11.lib
itkvnl_algo-4.11.lib
itkvnl-4.11.lib
ITKCommon-4.11.lib
ITKIOImageBase-4.11.lib
ITKIOVTK-4.11.lib
```

I can run the 'HelloWorld' ITK example, but when trying to register an image io factory (itk::PNGImageIOFactory::RegisterOneFactory()); I get a build failure with the following error:

```
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: __cdecl itk::PNGImageIOFactory::PNGImageIOFactory(void)" (??0PNGImageIOFactory@itk@@IEAA@XZ)
```

Am I missing anything? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `itkpng-4.11.lib`. Each reader has its own library. This was done to enable linking only the libraries which are needed by the application, not all of them.

The recommended way is to use CMake, so all your dependencies are managed automatically.